# mySQL - Get Tuples of entries with Same foreign attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following tables:

worker(**id**, fname, lname birthday)

works_on(**worker_id**, **task_id**).

Now, I want to get tuples of all workers working on same task.
My idea was to join worker with `works_on` and then joining with `worker` again. Basically this is working but I got duplicates like:

```
John Smith, Walther White

Walther White, John Smith
```

Hope you can help me.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.fname, t1.lname, t4.fname, t4.lname, t2.task_id
FROM worker AS t1
JOIN works_on AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.worker_id
JOIN works_on AS t3 ON t2.task_id = t3.task_id AND t2.worker_id < t3.worker_id
JOIN worker AS t4 ON t3.worker_id = t4.id
```

The trick here is this predicate in the `ON` clause of the second `JOIN` operation:

```
t2.worker_id < t3.worker_id
```

This gets the `id` of a worker working in the same project *provided* this `id` value is bigger than the `id` value of the `t1` `worker` table. This way, duplicate pairs are ruled out.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc7eb/3)

Comment: Thank you, can't believe that iv'e been stucked on this for such a long time:)

Comment: @JohnDew Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.